# How change the tomcat port in XAMPP

Tags: apache, tomcat, configuration, xampp, port

I have a problem.
I use XAMPP 1.7.7 under Windows XP.
I've changed the port in server.xml because I have this port with other application.
I start tomcat server from catabalina.bat perfect in the new port.
I change the port for tomcat in XAMPP.INI with the new port.
Restart the computer.
And I try again to start tomcat server from XAMPP Control Panel but I see log as "Busy port - Tomcat 8080".
The tomcat server start but I want to avoid this message in the XAMPP Control Panel.
So when you press de button for going to the tomcat by browser the url is with the old port.

Where can change the port?
What Can I do?

Comment: Which port did you change in server.xml?

Answer (score 3):

I have tried this with Xampp for Windows v7.2.1 and XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.2
Go to the xampp installation directory. \xampp  
You will find a file xampp-control.ini . Open it and go to the Service Ports section.
I have modified all the three tomcat ports as shown below. Earlier it was 8080, 8009 and 8005.

[image: Xampp service ports]

For the safe side also change the ports in the file server.xml under \xampp\tomcat\conf
change all the ports as required 
[image: Tomcat ports]

[xampp](/questions/tagged/xampp)

Answer (score 2):

most of the time the tomact port 8080 is blocked by oracle 10g's "TNSLSNR.EXE". Before start tomcat from XAMPP control panel, start the task manager, click on to the process tab of the task manager window.Find the "TNSLSNR.EXE" process. select "TNSLSNR.EXE", click on the end process button. If you don't show the "TNSLSNR.EXE" in the process list, then click show processes from all user button to find the "TNSLSNR.EXE". "TNSLSNR.EXE" process will be available in the processes list. Select "TNSLSNT.EXE", click on the end process button. After stopping the "TNSLSNR.EXE" start the tomcat from XAMPP control panel. Click on to the admin button of tomcat in xampp control panal. The admin page will run on browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is link to modify config

http://musingsofanitjedi.blogspot.in/2009/09/modifying-tomcat-admin-port-in-xampp.html

after that you have to start and stop service

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Xwamp 7.1.4 + then no need to do so many things for port changes.

Just go to XWamp panel > Config > click on "Tomcat tab" and changes the port no.
Restart your xWamp.

it will work.

Regard,
Pappu Mehta.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the steps Ram Sharma provided here, I had to also do the following to get my Tomcat to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the xampp directory, go to C:\xampp\tomcat and double click "catalina_start.bat" This should start up tomcat in the port you specified. you can check that it is running correctly by going to

```
http://localhost:`"custom-port"`
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He is already doing all that, except that he has the correct .bat filename and you don't. -1.

Answer (score 0):

You can Do One Thing.
Go to Your conf folder TomCat directory in Xampp Installation Directory.
for Example in my Computer it is C:\xampp\tomcat\conf.

Here you can find 'server' file.It is an XML file.
Open it using administrator rights,Search for tag 
change the Port to any 8001 to 8010.
Thats it!
Restart the Xampp Control Panel and Go to Browser And To Go to 
 http://localhost:8080 
There You Can See The Cat!